# How to improve performance on large left outer join?

Tags: sql-server-2008, left-join

These are my tables:

**Source_Artikelen** - columns: article - description (1.438.171 records)

**Source_LevArt** - columns: article - manufacturer part number (1.751.801 records)

... and this is the query I'm performing

```
SELECT a.Artikel,a.Omschrijving, l.Artikel_Leverancier
  FROM Source_Artikelen AS a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Source_LevArt AS l
    ON a.Artikel Like l.Artikel
```

This query was running tonight for more than 20 hours before I cancelled it manually.

So what am I trying to do?

I want to list down all articles from my table **Source_Artikelen**. Then I would like to see if there are manufacturer part numbers available in **Source_LevArt**.

- not every article from **Source_Artikelen** is present in **Source_LevArt**
- sometimes there are multiple manufacturer part numbers in **Source_LevArt** for one article

That's why I need to use a *LEFT OUTER JOIN*.

I've tried some things with indexes, but it's not really helping. Possibly I'm doing something wrong.

I can really use some help, as this is only the beginning of the query I'm writing.
I will have to add 2 other (large) tabes as left outer join later...

---

UPDATE 19/12/2016 16:24:
Hi piet.t

```
SELECT TOP(20) a.Artikel,a.Omschrijving, l.Artikel_Leverancier 
  FROM Source_Artikelen AS a 
       LEFT JOIN Source_LevArt AS l 
    ON a.Artikel LIKE l.Artikel
```

this takes 9 seconds

```
SELECT TOP(20) a.Artikel,a.Omschrijving, l.Artikel_Leverancier 
  FROM Source_Artikelen AS a 
       LEFT JOIN Source_LevArt AS l 
    ON a.Artikel = l.Artikel
```

this takes 1 second!

I really didn't know there was a difference as I'm not using wildcards.

Comment: is Source_Artikelen .Artikel a primary key and Source_LevArt.Artikel a foreign key?  you can also indicate as an "AND" after the "ON" (no where clause) `AND "manufacturer part numbers" is not null. replacing what's in quote with the field containing the part numbers. (assuming some could be null on records in source_levArt.  What should happen then is the filter is applied to the 2nd table before the join occurs reducing the number of records the query has to join.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is to get rid of the `like` in the join-condition since you seem to only want exact matches, so try `ON a.Artikel = l.Artikel` and see if this speeds things up.

Comment: @vlatro "I really didn't know there was a difference as I'm not using wildcards." You know that but the SQL-processor does not since there might be a `%` or `_` hidden in the contents of `l.Artikel`

Comment: Thank you @piet.t

Answer (score 0):

Use = instead of like.

These 2 indexes should give you the best performance for a Select.

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON Source_Artikelen(Artikel) INCLUDE(Omschrijving);

CREATE INDEX idx ON Source_LevArt(Artikel) INCLUDE(Artikel_Leverancier);
```

If you implement them and try your SELECT again, can you please upload a copy of your execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by Paul White here :[Dynamic Seeks and Hidden Implicit Conversions](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx)

using like even when there is exact match tends to do a dynamic seek..which means knowing the column to be seeked at execution time,not at compilation time..

below is how .,column is derived for the tables in below example of mine..

> [Expr1005] = Scalar Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(12),[Aegon_X].[Sales].[Orders].[custid] as [o].[custid],0)),
> [Expr1006] = Scalar Operator(**LikeRangeStart**(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(12),[Aegon_X].[Sales].[Orders].[custid] as [o].[custid],0))),
> [Expr1007] = Scalar Operator(**LikeRangeEnd**(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(12),[Aegon_X].[Sales].[Orders].[custid] as [o].[custid],0))),
> [Expr1008] = Scalar Operator(**LikeRangeInfo**(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(12),[Aegon_X].[Sales].[Orders].[custid] as [o].[custid],0)))

below is what Paul describes ,how those are derived

> The upper tooltip shows that the Compute Scalar uses three internal functions, LikeRangeStart, LikeRangeEnd, and LikeRangeInfo.
>
> The first two functions describe the range as an open interval.  The third function returns a set of flags encoded in an integer, that are used internally to define certain seek properties for the Storage Engine.  The lower tooltip shows the seek on the open interval described by the result of LikeRangeStart and LikeRangeEnd, and the application of the residual predicate ‘LIKE @Like’.

So in summary ,using like SQL uses dynamic seek to derive seek properties at compile time  ..

Examples below showing different plans

**using like   :**
I really didn't know there was a difference as I'm not using wildcards.

```
select top 10* from sales.orders o
join
sales.customers c
on c.custid like o.custid
```

**plan:**
[image]

**Now when using exact match..**

```
 select top 10* from sales.orders o
    join
    sales.customers c
    on c.custid =o.custid
```

[image]

You can see merge join plan